# Event handler on togglebutton

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding, togglebutton

I am creating `ToggleButton` and if I do not check it, it looks this:

[image: ToggleButton as swith that is unchecked (off).]

If I check it, it looks like this:

[image: ToggleButton as swith that is checked (on) with a ComboBox next to it.]

I use MaterialDesign and this is my code:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock  Text="Máy in hóa đơn :"
       Foreground="White" Margin="15,20,0,0"/>
    <ToggleButton   VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,20,0,0"/>
</Grid>
```

I want to show the `ComboBox` if the `ToggleButton` is checked, otherwise hide it. I don't know how to do so. I do not want to write in code behind.

Comment: I have done about button design. I want to handle the button like the following picture that I posted

Comment: i want if i click on the button it will show the combobox otherwise hide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign an `x:Name` to the `ToggleButton` and create a `Style` for the `ComboBox` which uses a `DataTrigger` that changes its `Visibility` depending on the `IsChecked` property of the `ToggleButton`. The binding uses the [`ElementName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.elementname?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Data.Binding.ElementName);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=windowsdesktop-6.0) to refer to the `ToggleButton`.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
   <TextBlock Text="Máy in hóa đơn :" Foreground="White" Margin="15,20,0,0" />
   <ToggleButton x:Name="MyToggleButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,20,0,0" />
   <ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Top">
      <ComboBox.Style>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
               <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=MyToggleButton}" Value="True">
                  <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
               </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
      </ComboBox.Style>
   </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Alternatively, use the built-in [`BooleanToVisibilityConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Controls.BooleanToVisibilityConverter);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=windowsdesktop-6.0) in the `Visibility` binding.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
   <StackPanel.Resources>
      <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
   </StackPanel.Resources>
   <TextBlock Text="Máy in hóa đơn :" Foreground="White" Margin="15,20,0,0" />
   <ToggleButton x:Name="MyToggleButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,20,0,0" />
   <ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=MyToggleButton, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
</StackPanel>
```